# Exception : The specified type member 'LineColor' is not supported in LINQ to Entities

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I got below exception when assigning value in byte[] using linq

"The specified type member 'LineColor' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported."

below is code

```
(from v in _DWEntities.DimScheduleJourneys
                join od in _DWEntities.OperatingDateVehicleJourneyMappings on v.VehicleJourneyUID equals od.VehicleJourneyUID
                where od.OperatingDateKey == _operatingDate && (vehicleJourneyUID == null || v.VehicleJourneyUID == vehicleJourneyUID)
                && (v.ScheduleDeparture != null && v.ScheduleDeparture != "" && v.ScheduleArrival != null && v.ScheduleArrival != "")
                select new ScheduleJourney
                {
                    VehicleJourneyUID = v.VehicleJourneyUID,
                    VehicleJourneyID = v.VehicleJourneyID,
                    TransportMode = v.TransportMode,
                    JourneyCode = v.JourneyCode == null ? v.VehicleJourneyCode : v.JourneyCode,
                    DepartureTime = v.ScheduleDeparture,
                    DirectionID = v.DirectionID,
                    BlockID = od.BlockId.Value,
                    BlockNumber = od.BlockNumber,
                    DutyBoard = od.DutyBoard,
                    DutyBoardID = od.DutyBoardID,
                    LineUID = v.LineUId,
                    LineName = v.LineName,
                    LineColor = v.LineColor,
                    //LineColor = v.LineName,
                    ServiceID = v.ServiceID,
                    ServiceCode = v.ServiceCode,
                    OperatorID = v.OperatorId,
                    OperatorCode = v.OperatorCode,
                    OperatorName = v.OperatorName,
                    JourneyPatternUID = v.JourneyPatternUID,
                    FirstStopPoint = v.FirstStopPoint,
                    LastStoppoint = v.LastStopPoint,
                    FirstStopPointName = v.FirstStopPointName,
                    LastStopPointName = v.LastStopPointName,
                    EndTime = v.ScheduleArrival,
                    OperatingDate = od.OperatingDate,
                    JourneyAccessibility = v.WheelchairAccessible.HasValue ? v.WheelchairAccessible.Value : false,
                    TenantId = v.TenantId.HasValue ? v.TenantId.Value : new Guid(),
                    DeadRunStartTime = v.DeadRunStartTime,
                    DeadRunEndTime = v.DeadRunEndTime,
                    MarketingName = v.MarketingName,
                    PrivateCode = v.PrivateCode,
                    //   GarageID = v.GarageID,
                    GarageCode = v.GarageCode,
                    IsFrequentService = v.FrequentService.HasValue ? v.FrequentService.Value : false,
                    FrequentServiceInterval = v.ScheduleFrequency,
                    Origin = v.Origin,
                    Destination = v.Destination,
                    IsMasterJourney = v.IsMasterJourney
                });
```

Here my LineColor is byte[]

Please help to solve this exception

thanks in advance

Comment: Can you post the whole declaration of LineColor in the entity class?

Comment: LineColor isn't marked as NotMapped,right?

Comment: In sql LineColor data type is varbinary and entity (C#) class is byte[]. So every time entity take null value in line color.

Comment: As per My RND entity is not able to get varbinary datatype value. I am not sure but due to null Linq is not able to handle